# Compile MvcContrib Portable Area with aspnet_compiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, publish, mvccontrib, portable-areas

I have a .net mvc 2 web application. I deployed this application using aspnet_compiler and a nant build file

like

```
 <target name="deploy.advance.application"> 
    <exec program="${aspnet.compiler}" commandline='-f -u -c -p ${dir.website.advance.application} -v temp ${dir.publish.advance.application}'  /> 
    <mkdir dir="${dir.publish.advance.application}\App_Data" />
  </target>
```

Now I started to implment PortableArea, at least LoginArea with all pages embedded,  required by the MvcContrib PA.

On my local machine works fine, but on testing environment (when I deploy the application with aspnet_compiler) the application could not found Login.aspx view.

So the question is how to deploy such applications? There is a directive from aspnet_compiler to tell the compiler that there are some embedded resources?

Thanks

Comment: Found a work around. After TeamCity builds I just copy necessary folders and files. But any way would like to see an elegant deployment task :)

Comment: I totally agree, im using Cruise Control and its an MVC 1 application. Im trying to create a precompiled website but instead it creates one without the views. Do you know whether it requires you to install .NET Framework 4.0 ... might be the 2.0 compiler is not MVC aware ...